# Dojo build - get rid of *.consoleStripped.js files

Tags: build, dojo

I recently upgraded our dojo build from dojo 1.9.1 to 1.9.10, and for some reason now I am seeing `*.consoleStripped.js` files left over from the optimizer. It's great that it's removing the console statements, but I would expect these would be intermediate files not included in the final build product. When I look at `util/build/transforms/optimizer/closure.js`, I don't see any code to remove the files. I can manually remove them with a `find blah blah | xargs rm`, but is there a setting to remove these files after they are used to create the final minimized files? I can't seem to find one. Or is there some reason that I am missing to deploy these "consoleStripped" files alongside the other files (mimized, uncompressed, and map)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`stripConsole: "normal"`

to strip from your build all console.

Use:

`layerOptimize: "closure"`

to switch to closure if you need too.

Full documentation related to Dojo Build Optimization can be found here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/

Edit:

Dojo build cannot delete you `*.consoleStripped.js` for that you need to use grunt, gulp or another external tool.

Comment: Yes, those are my current settings. What I am observing is that the build leaves behind all the intermediate `*.consoleStripped.js` files, so I'm looking for a setting that causes the build to clean those up after it's done with them, since I don't really want to deploy them with the release.

Comment: @xdhmoore thanks for clarification, DOJO will not delete for you files *.consoleStripped.js, for that you could use any other external tools, like gulp or grunt example npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-clean

Answer (score 0):

I believe that dojo-build uses ShrinkSafe by default, and not Google Closure [(ref)](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/#build-optimization).

Either way, both have their codes hidden away in Java .jar files.

I remove these files by adding the below to the very end of my build script - ensuring that I have 'cd' to the distribution folder first.

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "(.*\.bak|.*\.consoleStripped\.js|.*\.uncompressed\.js|.*\.map)$" -type f -delete
```

Comment: Yes, that's my current solution. I was hoping to find something better. I am unclear about what role Closure has in their build, but I believe the relevant code that creates the "consoleStripped" files is in [closure.js](https://github.com/dojo/util/blob/1.9.1/build/transforms/optimizer/closure.js) and [stripConsole.js](https://github.com/dojo/util/blob/1.9.1/build/transforms/optimizer/stripConsole.js)

Comment: I agree IMO ShrinkSafe  is the default.